# Extjs component inside Ext.XTemplate on EXTJS 4

Tags: extjs, components, extjs4, render

I'm trying to add extjs components to tpl panel. 
Is there anyway to insert component to tpl like this

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{ 
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(), 
    data: {},  
    listeners:{
        afterrender:function(){
            var renderSelector = Ext.query('div.comment-add-textarea'); 
                for(var i in renderSelector){
                    Ext.create('Ext.form.field.TextArea',{
                        height:300,
                        renderTo:renderSelector[i]
                    });   
                } 
        }
    },
    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div class="comment-add-textarea"></div>',
        '</tpl>',{
          compiled:true
        })
});​
```

Comment: check here http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-114317.html

Comment: Ah i found my problem. it's working when i change afterrender event to refresh event

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    data: {},
    listeners: {
        refresh: function() {
            var renderSelector = Ext.query('div.comment-add-textarea');
            for (var i in renderSelector) {
                Ext.create('Ext.form.field.TextArea', {
                    height: 300,
                    renderTo: renderSelector[i]
                });
            }
        }
    },
    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div class="comment-add-textarea"></div>',
        '</tpl>', {
            compiled: true
    })
});
```