# Is it possible to use an xtype inside an ExtJS template

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am wondering if I can do something like this in ExtJS. I am creating my own button as an xtype and want it to be used in the table row I am creating.

```
testTpl:  Ext.DomHelper.createTemplate(
    {
        tag: 'tbody',
        children: [
            {
                tag: 'tr',
                cls: 'test-row',
                children:[{
                    tag: 'td',
                    cls: 'test-table-cell test-class1',
                    html: '{value1}'
                    },
                    {
                       tag: 'td',
                       xtype:'myxtype'
                       cls: 'test-table-cell test-class2',
                       html: '{value2}'
                    }]
             }]
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to place ExtJS components inside of a extjs template. Though what you could do is to create a placeholder in your template and render ExtJS components into that placeholder in the render function.

Here are some links with examples:

[ExtJS 4.2.1 - add textfield to an XTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956817/extjs-4-2-1-add-textfield-to-an-xtemplate)

[Extjs component inside Ext.XTemplate on EXTJS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649832/extjs-component-inside-ext-xtemplate-on-extjs-4)