# Adding sencha component in expandedrow

Tags: extjs

I want to Add grid panel that will expanded when 
the user DblClick on the row 
so I can add more details to the row 
does it there any other properties that should I add too

```
     this.msGroupFlowGridPanel = msGroupFlowGridPanel = new Ext.grid.Panel(
     {
        itemId: "msGroupFlowGridPanel",
        store: msGroupFlowStore,
        columns:
        [
           {
              text: this.msGroupFlow_IssueText,
              dataIndex: "issue",
              flex: 1,
              scope: this,
              editor:
              {
                 xtype: "combobox",
                 store: issueStore,
                 displayField: "text",
                 valueField: "value",
                 forceSelection: true,
                 queryMode: "local"
              }

           },
           {
              text: this.msGroupFlow_NextIssueText,
              dataIndex: "nextIssue",
              flex: 1,
              editor:
              {
                 xtype: "combobox",
                 store: issueStore,
                 displayField: "text",
                 valueField: "value",
                 forceSelection: true,
                 queryMode: "local"
              } 
           },
           {
              xtype: "actioncolumn",
              flex: 1,
              scope: this,
              text: this.deleteText,
              icon: "Images/Grid_Delete.png",
              handler: this.onDeleteActionColumnClick
           }
        ],
        plugins:
        [
           {
              ptype: "cellediting",
              clicksToEdit: 1
           },
           {
              ptype: 'rowexpander',
              rowBodyTpl:
              [
                  '<b> here is the place where i want to add grid panel</b>  '
              ]
           }
        ]
     });
```

I want to add grid panel in rowBodyTpl: ?? like this one in the picture
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible to just create a new xtype:'gridpanel' within the template.

[Is it possible to use an xtype inside an ExtJS template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292024/is-it-possible-to-use-an-xtype-inside-an-extjs-template)

What i would do is create an html table template that will hold respective data. Best of luck